# Adjust font size in UisegmentControl

Tags: swift, fonts, uilabel, uisegmentedcontrol

how can I adjustfontsize in segmentcontrol like a label that it has a property named adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth so if the text is larger that label width the font size will become smaller to fit the width how can I. do same for uisegmetncontrol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setTitleTextAttrribute to set font for for segment control

```
  SegmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: REGULAR_FONT, size: 13.0)],
                                                           for: UIControlState())
   SegmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: BOLD_FONT, size: 13.0)], for:.selected)
```

Added the swift version of answer mentioned in the comment:-

```
 func setWidthTosegmetControl(view :UIView)  {
        let subviews = view.subviews
        for subview in subviews {
            if subview is UILabel {
                let label: UILabel? = (subview as? UILabel)
                print("label found: \(label?.text)")
                label?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
                label?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
            }else {
                setWidthTosegmetControl(view: subview)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: looking for swift version

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it in the view controller and call the function in viewDidAppear.

```
func autoshrinkSegmentFontSize() {
    for subview in segments.subviews {
        for label in subview.subviews {
            if let myLabel = subview as? UILabel {
                myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
                myLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
            }
        }
    }
}
```